# Using a for loop to count the number of total letters and the number of a specific letter\

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, counter

For a school project I have to write a function that counts the number of letters in a string, but also counts the number of a specific letter, however it only seems to increase the total letter count when it is the specified letter. I don't understand why it isn't registering ascii_lowercase as the lower case alphabet in 3.7, unless i have drastically misunderstood something.

```
def analyze_string(quote, search_letter):
    count_letters = 0
    count_occurance = 0
    phrase = quote.lower()
    letter = string.ascii_lowercase
    length = len(phrase)
    for i in phrase:
        if i == letter:
            count_letters = count_letters + 1
        elif i == search_letter:
            count_letters = count_letters + 1
            count_occurance = count_occurance + 1
        else:
            count_letters = count_letters + 0

    return count_letters, count_occurance
```

Comment: Why `count_letters = count_letters + 0` ? Anything + `0` = Anything.

Comment: Using the REPL or a print statement to see what `string.ascii_lowercase` contained may have helped answer why the `i == letter` conditional wasn't working ;) Just a bit more digging and you would have figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

This line is problematic:

```
if i == letter:
```

You have assigned to `letter` a string containing all lowercase letters via `string.ascii_lowercase`. But `i` is just **one** letter. You can instead use:

```
if i in letter:
    # ...
```

Checking membership of a string takes O(*n*) time. You may wish to use `set` to reduce this to O(1) beforehand via a conversion:

```
letter = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

You then need to *reverse* the order of your `if` statements so that the check for `search_letter` takes precedence. Otherwise, if `search_letter` exists in `letter`, the second condition will never be met.

```
for i in phrase:
    if i == search_letter:
        count_letters = count_letters + 1
        count_occurance = count_occurance + 1
    elif i in letter:
        count_letters = count_letters + 1
```

Note the below lines are redundant, you can safely remove them:

```
else:
    count_letters = count_letters + 0
```

Comment: There's also an issue with the order of if-statements. The first check `i in letter` will presumably catch the specific letter you are trying to count.